# Conditional Calculation in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a transactions table with some hypothetical data that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions(
    store_id INT,
    cust_id INT,
    txn_id INT,
    txn_date BIGINT,
    amt FLOAT,
    industry INT);

INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(200,1,1,20200101,21.01,1000);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(200,2,2,20200102,20.01,1000);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(200,2,3,20200103,19.00,1000);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(200,3,4,20200103,19.00,1000);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(300,2,5,20200104,1.39,2000);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(300,1,6,20200105,12.24,2000);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(300,1,7,20200105,25.02,2000);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(400,2,8,20200106,103.1,1000);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES(400,2,9,20200107,21.3,1000);
```

I would like to create a new table `results` that calculates, for each store, the percentage of transactions in its industry that it processed. For example, store 200 is in industry 1000 and store 200 had 4 of the 6 transactions in industry 1000, or 0.67. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select store_id, industry,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over (partition by industry) as ratio
from transactions t
group by store_id, industry;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f21bc56f4ef39be936a4ef995ade9df) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the job with a sub-request :

```
SELECT DISTINCT store_id, industry,
    ( (SELECT COUNT(store_id) FROM transactions WHERE store_id = main.store_id)
     / (SELECT COUNT(store_id) FROM transactions WHERE industry = main.industry)) as percent
FROM transactions as main
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
select t1.store_id,CAST(count(*) AS float)/CAST (total AS FLOAT) as pourcentage 
from transactions t1 
join 
(SELECT t.industry as industr,COUNT(*) as total  
from transactions t 
GROUP by t.industry )
on industr = t1.industry 
group by store_id;
```